# How to traverse a Map having Keys of Object Type using Sightly?

Tags: aem, sightly

I've started working in Sightly just this week, so I'm pretty new to this. But, while working with it, I got a requirement of passing data from back-end to front end in the form of a Map containing keys of Page type and corresponding values of List type as seen in the following signature :

```
           public Map<Page, List<Page>> getComponentMap();
```

Now the documentation on https://goo.gl/sylWTW states that a map can be traversed in the following way :

```
  <p data-sly-repeat="${myMap}">
         <span>key: ${item}</span>
         <span>value: ${myMap[item]}</span>
  </p>
```

But, when I tried it, it works if Keys are of String Type, but doesn't if I pass keys of other Object types, like 'Page' type in my case.
I tried the following code and works for displaying the keys, but throws Illegal Argument Exception after adding Line No. 6 :

```
1    <div data-sly-use.jcomp="JavaComponent">
2        <ul data-sly-repeat.page="${jcomp.componentMap}">
3        <li>
4            <ul>
5                <li class="parent"><a href="${page.path}.html">${page.title} :</a></li>            
6                <li data-sly-repeat.subpage="${jcomp.componentMap[page]}"><a href="${subpage.path}.html">${subpage.title} </a></li>
7            </ul>
8        </li>
9        </ul>
10    </div>
```

Lists work fine for any type of Objects, so for my requirement of Page's Title, Path and Children, I achieved it by using a List of Map, where Map contains Names of Page's required info.

I don't know if it is supposed to be like that or not for Map or I'm doing something wrong, but it would be of a great help to know the reason and/or a better work-around for similar cases.

Comment: Can you update this answer with a solution if one was found? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on Line 6: (not sure if it works):

```
<li data-sly-repeat.subpage="${jcomp.componentMap[page]}">
<a href="${jcomp.componentMap[page].subpage.path}.html">${jcomp.componentMap[page].subpage.title} </a></li>`
```

An example of a similar one but using LIST, that works for me is as follows:

```
<div data-sly-list.item="${jsonHelper.parsedJSON}" data-sly-unwrap>
<h3 class="panel-title">${jsonHelper.parsedJSON[item].name @ context='html'}</h3>
<div class="panel-body" data-sly-list.subitem="${jsonHelper.parsedJSON[item].commodityList}">
${jsonHelper.parsedJSON[item].commodityList[subitem].name @ context='html'}
</div>
</div>
```

As this was getting complicated, we started to use SlingModels. I have an example here, if you're interested:
[How to display values in a List of a SlingModel using Sightly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31146716/how-to-display-values-in-a-list-of-a-slingmodel-using-sightly)